# Emmet in VS Code is expanding "do" into a html code in my Elixir .ex file after tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir, emmet

When I type, for example:

```
def Hello do
```

and after o in do I press the tab I get this:

```
def Hello do <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I even see it via autocomplete popup before hitting the tab key as:

```
doc           Emmet Abbreviation
```

But the problem is that I don't mean html do-cumment but a standard do end block in elixir

and I want someting like

```
def Hello do 

end
```

Where to stop emmet from hijacking the def do end expantion in my .ex file?

By the way, it works if I press tab right after def, but I want to be able to add end after do and not the html boilerplate too.

Comment: check `emmet.includeLanguages` in your `settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

IntelliSense is suggesting Emmet abbreviations to you when you're typing. If you press `Tab`, you accept the highlighted suggestion, which in your case, is the Emmet HTML document template.

Whenever such a popup appears while typing, you can simply press `ESC` to dismiss the IntelliSense popup, which then allows you to type whatever you want.